# Sql server: Keeping track of counts in a View?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Using Sql Server 2008, would it be appropriate to use a View to keep track of table counts. E.g.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].UserCounts    
    SELECT     O.UserId, Count(O.OrderId) AS OrderCount
    FROM       User U INNER JOIN Orders O ON U.UserId = O.UserId
    GROUP BY O.UserId
```

Is this a viable solution having 100.000 users and approx. 500.000 orders?

Thanks in advance,
Anders

Answer (score 1):

You can create an indexed view, but you must use [`COUNT_BIG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx) instead:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.UserCounts    
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT     O.UserId, 
      COUNT_BIG(O.OrderId) AS OrderCount
    FROM       dbo.User U 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Orders O ON U.UserId = O.UserId
    GROUP BY O.UserId;
go

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdxUserCounts on dbo.UserCounts(UserId);
go
```

This way the engine will maintain the counts up to date, as opposed to count them every time you query the view. The drawback is contention, you cannot create/delete orders for the same user from different transactions.

Comment: Thank you! Great suggestion. Do you see a high risks of contention if the db are accessed from several websites?

Comment: Only you can answer that question :)

Answer (score 0):

This view will be executing the inline query every time you access this view. So I think just creating the index on view will not help.The main thing is to have proper indexes on the underlying 2 tables Users and Orders.